# Google play защита закрывает работающее приложение

Tags: android, qt5, google-play

Столкнулся с проблемой в заголовке, не понимаю почему блокирует, в лог кате нахожу только сообщение с просьбой удалить программу и завершение работы ПО. Устройство Samsung sm-t515 андройд 9, на других устройствах подобного поведения не наблюдается. ПО не публикуется в Goole Play, устанавливается приложением-админом устройства, его же просит выполнить определённые действия, такие как установка удаление другого ПО. Отключать защиту не желательно. ПО написано на QT5.15.2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
12-15 11:14:59.114 I/Finsky  (11517): [935] akhb.b(1): Attempting to stop application: com.app.myapp
12-15 11:14:59.122 I/ActivityManager( 4008): Force stopping com.app.myapp appid=10146 user=0: from pid 11517 caller android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact:841 
12-15 11:14:59.124 I/ActivityManager( 4008): Killing 12120:com.app.myapp/u0a146 (adj 900): stop com.app.myapp,from pid 11517 caller android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact:841 
12-15 11:14:59.125 W/libprocessgroup( 4008): kill(-12120, 9) failed: No such process
12-15 11:14:59.133 I/ActivityManager( 4008): Killing 12219:com.app.myapp:qt_service/u0a146 (adj 200): stop com.app.myapp,from pid 11517 caller android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact:841 
12-15 11:14:59.135 W/ActivityManager( 4008): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.app.myapp/.UpdaterService in 1000ms
12-15 11:14:59.146 I/ActivityManager( 4008): Killing 12176:com.samsung.android.sm.provider/1000 (adj 906): empty #21
12-15 11:14:59.147 I/ActivityManager( 4008):   Force finishing activity ActivityRecord{fc40d8e u0 com.app.myapp/.ServiceLoaderActivity t26}
12-15 11:14:59.149 D/Telecom:SamsungPrebindingServiceImpl( 4008): onTopActivityChanged : ComponentInfo{com.app.myappui/com.app.myappui.DCUpdaterUIActivity}
12-15 11:14:59.158 I/ActivityManager( 4008):   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{2a2a54d u0 com.app.myapp/.UpdaterService}
12-15 11:14:59.167 I/WindowManager( 4008): Cancelling animation restarting=false, leash=null, surface=Surface(name=AppWindowToken{b4911bc token=Token{c6f39af ActivityRecord{fc40d8e u0 com.app.myapp/.ServiceLoaderActivity t26}}})/@0x570dc52, parent=Surface(name=Task=26)/@0xd9afb23
12-15 11:14:59.168 I/chatty  ( 4008): uid=1000(system) ActivityManager identical 7 lines
12-15 11:14:59.174 W/libprocessgroup( 4008): kill(-12120, 9) failed: No such process
12-15 11:14:59.176 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3624): id=315 Removed Task=26#0 (1/65)
12-15 11:14:59.176 W/SurfaceFlinger( 3624): Attempting to destroy on removed layer: AppWindowToken{b4911bc token=Token{c6f39af ActivityRecord{fc40d8e u0 com.app.myapp/.ServiceLoaderActivity t26}}}#0
12-15 11:14:59.180 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3624): id=314 Removed animation background stackId=10#0 (0/63)
12-15 11:14:59.181 W/libprocessgroup( 4008): kill(-12120, 9) failed: No such process
12-15 11:14:59.183 I/SurfaceFlinger( 3624): id=313 Removed Stack=10#0 (4/62)
12-15 11:14:59.185 D/SamsungAlarmManager( 4008): Remove alarm for next reason : android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED : package: com.app.myapp
12-15 11:14:59.187 I/Zygote  ( 3591): Process 12176 exited due to signal (9)
12-15 11:14:59.187 I/Layer   ( 3624): id=315 onRemoved Task=26#0 
12-15 11:14:59.187 I/Layer   ( 3624): id=316 onRemoved AppWindowToken{b4911bc token=Token{c6f39af ActivityRecord{fc40d8e u0 com.app.myapp/.ServiceLoaderActivity t26}}}#0 
12-15 11:14:59.187 I/Layer   ( 3624): id=314 onRemoved animation background stackId=10#0 
12-15 11:14:59.187 I/Layer   ( 3624): id=313 onRemoved Stack=10#0 
12-15 11:14:59.195 E/Telephony( 4350): PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
12-15 11:14:59.195 D/CarrierSvcBindHelper( 4350): No carrier app for: 0
12-15 11:14:59.196 W/BroadcastQueue( 4008): Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED dat=package:com.app.myapp flg=0x10 (has extras) } to android/com.kddi.android.CpaNotiReceiver
12-15 11:14:59.198 W/libprocessgroup( 4008): kill(-12120, 9) failed: No such process
12-15 11:14:59.200 I/Zygote  ( 3591): Process 12219 exited due to signal (9)
12-15 11:14:59.205 W/libprocessgroup( 4008): kill(-12120, 9) failed: No such process
12-15 11:14:59.210 W/libprocessgroup( 4008): kill(-12120, 9) failed: No such process
12-15 11:14:59.216 I/Zygote  ( 3591): Process 12120 exited due to signal (9)
12-15 11:14:59.216 W/libprocessgroup( 4008): kill(-12120, 9) failed: No such process
12-15 11:14:59.216 I/libprocessgroup( 4008): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10146 pid 12120 in 91ms
12-15 11:14:59.216 W/libprocessgroup( 4008): kill(-12219, 9) failed: No such process
12-15 11:14:59.217 I/libprocessgroup( 4008): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10146 pid 12219 in 0ms
12-15 11:14:59.217 W/libprocessgroup( 4008): kill(-12176, 9) failed: No such process
12-15 11:14:59.217 I/libprocessgroup( 4008): Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1000 pid 12176 in 0ms
12-15 11:14:59.218 D/InputTransport( 4008): Input channel destroyed: fd=502
12-15 11:14:59.218 D/InputTransport( 5937): Input channel destroyed: fd=63
12-15 11:14:59.219 W/ActivityManager( 4008): setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 12120
12-15 11:14:59.255 D/RecentsTaskLoadPlan( 5506): lastReportedWindowingMode is not exist.
12-15 11:14:59.260 D/RecentsTaskLoadPlan( 5506): lastReportedWindowingMode is not exist.
12-15 11:14:59.357 D/ApplicationPolicy( 4008): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = com.android.vending,userId = 0
12-15 11:14:59.358 D/API test( 4008): getContainerInfo: value is 
12-15 11:14:59.358 D/ApplicationPolicy( 4008): isStatusBarNotificationAllowedAsUser: packageName = com.android.vending,userId = 0
12-15 11:14:59.359 D/API test( 4008): getContainerInfo: value is 
12-15 11:14:59.367 I/Finsky  (11517): [935] wdm.a(18): Showing notification: [ID=package..remove..request..com.app.myapp, Tag=null, Title=Удалите опасное приложение, Message=Приложение "MyAppService" может быть вредоносным., channelId=security-and-errors, targetType=1, returnCode=-1, uiElementType=928]
12-15 11:14:59.484 D/Notification.Badge( 5506): [invalid] onNotificationPosted : StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.android.vending user=UserHandle{0} id=1676979212 tag=null key=0|com.android.vending|1676979212|null|10020: Notification(channel=security-and-errors pri=2 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null tick defaults=0x0 flags=0x110 color=0xfff4511e category=status actions=1 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0))
```

Comment: `ПО не публикуется в Goole Play` и `Google play защита закрывает работающее приложение` - непонятно

Comment: ПО не публикуется в Goole Play а устанавливается администратором устройства. Когда ПО запущено его закрывает Google play защита, что видно по логу "I/Finsky  (11517): [935] akhb.b(1): Attempting to stop application: com.app.myapp", пытаюсь понять что не нравиться Finsky  в моём ПО почему Google play защита считает "Приложение "MyAppService" может быть вредоносным.", но это происходит не при установке моего ПО, а при работе, установка проходит корректно.

Comment: `restart of crashed service com.app.myapp/.UpdaterService` - что за сервис?

Comment: мой сервис написанный на QT, именно его и прибивает

Comment: кажется я разобрался, не хватало разрешения android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE в манифесте